# curl transfer closed problem in Node.js JSON.parse

Tags: json, node.js

I got **curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining**
 problem in following code. console.log is working fine but I can't call url in browser and curl.

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
output=JSON.parse(output);
console.log(output);
res.end(output);
```

Comment: Which version of node are you using? Have you check with WireShark, what's acutally on-the-wire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because JSON.parse return the Object. res.end can't write object.

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1241